# How to use "most" or "the most" after a verb?

Tags: adverbs, superlatives

I can't make out which one of these questions is correct: "What impressed him most?" or "what impressed him the most?"
If both are correct, what is the difference in meaning and what kind of context do they derive from?

Comment: They are both correct, and there is no difference in meaning. "The" serves simply as an optional modifier of "most"